# Данные не сохраняются в БД

Tags: sqlite, curl, ruby, crud, sinatra

В учебном проекте данные, которые передаются через curl запрос, не сохраняются в базу  данных, например:

```
curl -X POST -i http://localhost:8080/users -d "firstname=Ivan" -d "lastname=Petrov" -d "age=30" -d "password=12345" -d "email=ivan@gmail.com"
```

не работает именно метод POST, с GET всё в порядке

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'erb'

set :port, 8080
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
set :views, "./views"


db = SQLite3::Database.open 'db.sql'
db.results_as_hash = true

db.execute 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
    (
      user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
      firstname TEXT,
      lastname TEXT,
      age INTEGER,
      password TEXT,
      email TEXT
    )' 

post '/users' do 
  @firstname = params[:firstname]
  @lastname = params[:lastname]
  @age = params[:age]
  @password = params[:password]
  @email = params[:email]
  db.execute 'INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, age, password, email)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [@firstname, @lastname, @age, @password, @email] 
end

get '/users' do  
    
    @all_users = db.execute 'SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id DESC'   
    erb :index      
end
```

Comment: Что в логах сервера?